# Does anybody know about Vadim's JQuery plugin Swappable

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Vadim's JQuery plugin](http://www.eslinstructor.net/demo/swappable/swappable_grid.html) Suppose i have four IDs which has different set of elements, I only want to swap three IDs elements and the fourth ID's elements is not swappable.

**IDs :** #foo, #zoo, #soo, #moo    [ each ID has different 'height' & "width" ]

**Swappable :**  #foo, #zoo, #soo  [ #moo is not swappable]

Q1. Want to check element's parent id is in among Swappable ID.  Line : 9

Q2. if drag & drop elements parent are swappable and different, suppose **drag_id.parentID = #foo, drop_id.parentID = #zoo** then swap it's height & width to each other. Line : 11,12,13

```
1.     $("#foo, #zoo, #soo").swappable({  
2.        [#moo elements can't be drag but act as a drop (target)]
3.              ...
4.           stop: function(event, ui) { 
5.              var drag_id = ui.item[0].id;
6                var target_id = event.originalEvent.target.id;
7.           
8.  i want to confirm drag & drop's parentID are swappable or not 
9.    e.g. ??  if($.ui.contains ( drag_id.parentID, target_id.parentID )) {
10      
11       if(drag_id.parentID != target_id.parentID)
12.           {  
13            then swap the width & height of elements to each other }
14           }  }   });
```

Comment: Bibhow, I'm not sure I completely understand your question and your goal. It looks like you assign the same set of elements to the 3 different parent elements (foo,zoo,soo), right? And what do you need to compare? You already have drug_id/drop_id. What exactly do you want  to have as a result?

Comment: @Vadimk: please check the Question once again, updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into using [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#items) widjet from JQuery UI? It's pretty awesome. And after you're done you can check the sort order and apply the height and width you want on each item.